# Using Muscle Milk but worried about its calorie content

Tags: muscle, protein

I am lactose intolerant. I researched many nutritions shop (in Turkey) and couldn't find lactose-free protein powders except Muscle Milk. I have also tried 1 serving from my friend's Muscle Milk and it does not disturb me. In short, I can use it.

I have belly fat though, and I am trying to lose it. I'm working out using the StrongLifts 5x5 program. It's my 3rd week, and I've lost 3 kilograms so far. My body also started having a shape. I'm really happy with this program . I'm not doing any cardio (running, biking, etc.) as part of my workout regimen.

I am concerned about the calorie content in Muscle Milk. Is it suitable for me to use it while on my StrongLifts 5x5 program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also lactose intolerant. The ultra filtered whey (sometimes marketed as 100%) works pretty well for my stomach, so maybe you should try using that. Otherwise you could use a pure egg protein, it is produced from egg whites and therefore have no lactose.

You seem to be in caloric deficit even with the muscle milk stuff, so in that sense it is suitable for you. So why change something that is working? If you still think you need to cut the extra calories, go ahead and get a pure protein.

Comment: I'll use protein powder first time.There are 150 calories per serving in MUscle Milk.I'm not sure it's acceptable amount or too much.

Comment: What is acceptable amount? . If you don't feel the need to spend the 150 kcal on something else, then that is an acceptable amount.
One could make the argument that you could spend those 150 kcal on something that contains better micronutrients like fruit and veggies. Other then that, as long as you lose fat mass, then all is well.

Comment: If i start using protein , it's mean extra 300 calories (2 serving per day) . As i said i'm not doing cardio because of this i'm worrying.What if i can't burn these 300 extra calories and stary getting fat ?

Comment: Well, you could take those 300 calories from your other diet. Or just buy egg protein, search for it on amazon.